# How do I translate "The state of California"?

Tags: translation, prepositions

If I want to translate a phrase like *the state of California*, how would I translate it? It feels like a literal translation of it with *de* would be impractical.

Answer (score 7):

*La ŝtato Kalifornio*

Quotation marks are not required. Certainly don't use *de*.

Comment: Do you have any reference about using _La ŝtato Kalifornio_?